# How to use HttpClient to query the AzureTable rest API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rest, azure-storage

I am not able to figure out how to set the authorization in the step below

```
    static string _address = "http://Foo.table.core.windows.net/BackupEntries()?select=RowKey";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Create an HttpClient instance
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("aa", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Steve Marx, please sign the request. You can find the detailed authentication schema on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx. It’s not difficult to sign the request, but the process can be a bit complicated. You can search the web to find some examples, such as http://blog.einbu.no/2009/08/authenticating-against-azure-table-storage/.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Answer (score -1):

This is old, but you can try it

```
    string Userid = string.Empty;
    string Pwd = string.Empty;



        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", Userid, Pwd));
        var authorization = "basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        fr.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
```

Comment: Windows Azure storage does not use basic auth. To construct a proper auth header, you need to sign the request (a combination of the resource being accessed and various headers).